# How to decode IdentityServer4 token

Tags: .net, oauth, jwt, identityserver4

I'm trying to decode an access token generated by **IdentityServer4 .net project** ... **from a PHP project** but I cannot do it and i `The JWT string must have two dots`
 .. then I tried to decode it from jwt.io but it gave me an invalid signature.

This is the data and the token I have:

```
{
"access_token": "FRHise20czCJyAUffrnalOMKuaQhfSUAJ29Hch2PcquNjazZnl81GB5YXgswgohj5AYD-BpYzEY_F5-o_uLw3ng8OFJWjU7GE3cl-q_FlbHgJj90mAB0-IgO0KOsp3PF90zMTx6INgP9S76paVkAisrPpjFLKpIoeYAVs-Jlb8kX2N9q6w3ZwmjCBaUJe1knNICFfiBjhwz195LX77F7F-ubX8MK-2FQ8Ws5Hod4Rh4-vz8Xhba_KPYiEl0_l5m_RBZPMu0N3N7jydJU1ZsJeiR-46rO2Db5X66G-fT9luP23ufJy-5NB6FKEaodze1O4ugJsk0ddECMgCpCGIr7lX4cJhppVT5PLDBbOMi4OmN-pdLQy9UHaMJXNQ4-bNWqKphiCTql_FcfJMg3jr-76xeymPssmcbbRtFfJzjPAPFWQYmi",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 86399,
"refresh_token": "bbf0e895e6d94b86ba478b6cbf9ae3b0",
"as:client_id": "7b3e99e5-3f69-4a82-8926-ebcd1dd570a5",
".issued": "Tue, 02 Apr 2019 16:22:24 GMT",
".expires": "Wed, 03 Apr 2019 16:22:24 GMT"
}
```

Comment: this is not a JWT and propably also not meant to be decoded.

Comment: so what is the encoding that used in IdentityServer4?

Comment: again, there's nothing to decode for you

Comment: probably or for sure ?!

Comment: What you might be seeing is a reference token described here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html